# JavaScript append at the end of each line of a text file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading a content of this text file with 3 rows:

"First choice was:

Second choice was:

Third choice was: "

I split by "\n" and I want to append a number at the end of each line which the user inputs. What the user inputs are 3 different numbers (from `select tags`) called "rank1", "rank2", "rank3" and I want to have each number at the end of each line of the newly created text file.

JavaScript:

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("data1.txt", "utf-8"); 
var lines = data.split("\n");

lines.forEach(function(line){
var newLine = line + /*What should be appended (rank1,rank2,rank3)*/;
var output = fs.appendFileSync('file', newLine, 'utf8');
})
```

The select tags:

```
<select name="rank1" size="1">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>

</select>

<select name="rank2" size="1">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>

</select>

<select name="rank3" size="1">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Expected output:

"First choice was: 1
 Second choice was: 3
 Third choice was: 2 "

How can I implement this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Read a Node.js tutorial. This is hardly an appropriate question.

Comment: How do you get the selected values in your JavaScript code?

Comment: @31piy The html file and the JavaScript file are connected. Then I have a submit button that reads and writes the new file. Thank you!

Comment: Just an idea, but create 3 variables in javascript for rank1,2,3. Do an onchange on the selects and in the onchange append the values of the selects to the variables. Then you can add them where you want whenever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a one-liner for what you want to do:

```
file.split('\n').map( (line) => line + choices.shift() ).join('\n')
```

Also, all this can be done asynchronously:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const choices = [ "rank1", "rank2", "rank3" ];

fs.readFile(
    './data1.txt',
    'utf-8',
    (err, file) => fs.writeFile(
        './data1.txt',
        file.split('\n').map( (line) => line + choices.shift() ).join('\n'),
        (err) => {}
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead you can use `for` loop to loop over the lines and `select` elements as well then export the output to file.

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("data1.txt", "utf-8"); 
var lines = data.split("\n");
var output;  
for(var i =0; i < lines.length;i++){
  var newLine = lines[i] + document.getElementsByName('rank'+(i+1))[0].value;
     output += newline; 
}

 fs.appendFileSync('file', output, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('rank1')[0].value
document.getElementsByName('rank2')[0].value
document.getElementsByName('rank3')[0].value
```

Comment: Don't use a method that returns a collection and then select the first element in the collection, just use querySelector if you're selecting a single element